# Menu elements jumping when zooming

Tags: html, css

The problem is as follows:  I have a basic unordered list which I turn into a horizontal menu using css.  However while zooming in or out in browser, the menu items jump to the next line as such:

Unzoomed:

|Menu 1| |menu 2| |Menu 3| |Menu 4|

Zoomed:

|Menu 1| |menu 2| |Menu 3|
|Menu 4|

What can I do to keep the menu items from jumping like that?

Comment: Thats one really common problem I've seen. I think it's beacuse you gave the width in pixels, so when zoomed and rounded to the next width, the sum will become bigger than 100%. You could try using % dimensions instead of pixels.

Comment: Using % seems to have stabilised the issue for the most part.  Thank you SinistraD.

Comment: float the parent(ul)

also i have a jquery solution , if u want to align center the ul

Answer (score 3):

Try experimenting with fixed (minimum) dimensions of the ul (or possibly a div wrapping the ul) and give it an overflow setting. Something like:

```
ul {
    width: 750px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but if the items have a border, the last item will lose its right border.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with SinsitraD - leave a little leeway in there.  If you're using percents, I typically try to leave a ~2% allowance.  If you prefer px as your unit of choice, then a guesstimated 1-2% allowance will cover most rounding errors.

You'll probably find the zoom behavior is not consistent between browsers - that's because most browsers use different methods to calculate sizes when zooming.

Answer (score 0):

try applying a `position: relative` in `li` elements